# Get class by name and call method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, oop, design-patterns, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to build an ability where I can fetch a StrucType schema object using name.

For that,I have defined a trait:

```
package schema

import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

trait ISchema {

  def schema(): StructType

}
```

And I am implementing this as follows:

```
package schema

import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{BooleanType, DateType, DecimalType, IntegerType, StringType, StructType}

object StaticPortfolio extends ISchema {

  override def schema(): StructType = new StructType()
    .add("account_number", StringType)
    .add("loan_amount", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("disburse_date", DateType)
    .add("start_date", DateType)
    .add("disbursed_amount", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("capitalized_interest", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("principal_outstanding_amount", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("principal_due", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("principal_paid", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("principal_not_paid", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("interest_due", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("interest_paid", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("interest_outstanding_amount", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("late_fee", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("late_fee_amount_paid", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("bounce_fee", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("bounce_fee_amount_paid", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("dpd_bucket", IntegerType)
    .add("dpd", IntegerType)
    .add("is_due_today", BooleanType)
    .add("status", StringType)
    .add("annual_rate_of_interest", DecimalType(38,6))
    .add("year", StringType)
    .add("month", StringType)
    .add("day", StringType)
}
```

Now I'm trying to get this `StrucType` schema object as follows:

```
val schemaName = "StaticPortfolio"
val schemaObj = Class.forName("schema." + schemaName)
schemaObj.schema
```

But I get `value schema is not a member of Class[?0]`

I also tried:

```
val schemaObj:ISchema = Class.forName("schema.StaticPortfolio")
println(schemaObj.schema)
```

But I get this error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Class[?0] where type ?0
 required: schema.ISchema
    val schemaObj:ISchema = Class.forName("schema.StaticPortfolio")
```

Comment: The error is of-course, because `Class.forName("schema.StaticPortfolio")` returns `Class` object which does not contain that method. You need the object of the instance or call `StaticPortfolio.getSchema` directly?

Comment: @Jatin But I need to get the class `StaticPortfolio` by name. So, cannot call `StaticPortfolio.getSchema` directly

Comment: what is the scala version that you are using?

Comment: @Jatin: version 2.12.x

Answer (score 0):

It appears based on comments, that you wish to access the instance via reflection.

If it can be done, I suggest making `StaticPortfolio` a class instead of singleton object. Singleton objects are a bit notorious to access via reflection, and behavior of accessing might change across scala versions. Of-course because JVM as such does not have a concept of singleton-objects at byte code level. It is more of a pattern at the code level. If a class:

```
class StaticPortfolio extends ISchema {
  override def schema(): StructType = new StructType()....
}

val s: StaticPortfolio = Class.forName("schema.StaticPortfolio").newInstance().asInstanceOf[StaticPortfolio]
s.schema()
```

But if its not possible to convert it to a class. I would rather go for below approach rather than using hacks/scalameta with reflection:

```
 inputString match {
  case "schema.StaticPortfolio" => StaticPortfolio.schema()
}
```

Static safety is always better. As last resort:

```
val clazz = Class.forName("schema.StaticPortfolio2$")
val singleton = clazz.getField("MODULE$").get(clazz).asInstanceOf[ISchema]
println(singleton.schema())
```

Comment: I do not know the class before hand, so `val s: StaticPortfolio` I will not be able to do this. Cannot do `asInstanceOf[StaticPortfolio]` either. Assume class name coming as an argument

Comment: Edited the answer